# Vavr - append 2 Lists of type io.vavr.collection.List into a single List based on the fields

Tags: java, vavr

I have the below requirement, I have 2 Lists, one is EmployeeList and DepartmentList now I want to merge/append the 2 lists into another List(finalList) based on the fields in the example below.

```
List<Employee> list = List.of( new Employee(1,"aba",101),
        new Employee(2,"cdc",102),new Employee(3,"ded",102));
List<Department> list1 = List.of( new Department(101,"Dep1"),
        new Department(102,"Dep2"));
List <EmployeeDepartment> finalList = List.empty();
```

Below are the classes: `Employee`, `Department` and `EmployeeDepartment`.

```
public class EmployeeDepartment {

    Integer deptno;
    Integer empid;
    String empname;
---setters and Getters
}
public class Department {
    Integer deptno;
    String depname;
---setters and Getters
}
public class Employee {

    Integer empid;
    String empname;
    Integer deptno;
---setters and Getters
}
```

Comment: Could you share the expected output ? Do you want all combination between Employee and Department ?

Comment: Yes I want the fields deptno,empid,empname;

Comment: You didn't answer to my comment ... You have 3 Emp, 2 Dep, how many `EmployeeDepartment` should be created ?

Comment: Yes I need all the combinations between Employee and Department

Answer (score 1):

You may iterate on both lists and add the new `EmployeeDepartment` objects

```
List<EmployeeDepartment> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Employee e : list) {
    for (Department d : list1) {
        finalList.add(new EmployeeDepartment(e.getEmpid(), e.getEmpname(), d.getDeptno()));
    }
}
```

Or using `Stream`

```
List<EmployeeDepartment> finalList = list.stream()
        .flatMap(e -> list1.stream().map(d -> new EmployeeDepartment(e.getEmpid(), e.getEmpname(), d.getDeptno())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is the expected output (also `EmployeeDepartment` has all the fields that `Employee` has), but if you need to have all the combinations of elements in two lists then `crossProduct` is what you need:

```
class Lol {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> list = List.of(
            new Employee(1, "aba", 101),
            new Employee(2, "cdc", 102),
            new Employee(3, "ded", 102)
        );
        List<Department> list1 = List.of(
            new Department(101, "Dep1"),
            new Department(102, "Dep2")
        );
        final Iterator<Tuple2<Employee, Department>> tuple2s = list.crossProduct(list1);
        System.out.println(tuple2s.size());

    }
}
```

What you get is an iterator with 6 tuples.

If you need to get a `Department` for every `Employee` using `deptno` then it would be much better to convert the second collection to `Map<Integer, Department>` and use it to map the first collection.